# Topology without intersection

Tags: general-topology

A **topology** consists of a pair $(T,Opens)$ where $T$ is a nonempty set and $Opens\subseteq powerset(T)$ is closed under

1. arbitrary (possibly infinite, possibly empty) unions and
2. finite (possibly empty) intersections.

**Question:** can anyone provide literature references for where structures $(T,Opens)$ have been studied that have closure condition 1 but not necessarily closure condition 2.  Thus, an arbitrary union of opens is open, but an intersection of opens need not be open?

Thanks.

Comment: The intersection property is very useful

Comment: Google "union-closed family".

Comment: Try Császár 's [generalised topologies](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1019713018007).

Comment: I’ve never heard of anyone requiring a topological space to be nonempty. What is the motivation for this?

Comment: @MarkSaving I’ve found it to be quite common. It’s convenient whenever you want to state a theorem whose statement or proof involves making reference to elements of the space. Writing, “let (-) be a *nonempty* space” is tedious in repetition. That said, the empty space is convenient to have for categorical reasons